# Can LAN affect internet speed in case of using android camera as a webcam?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, android, webcam

I would like to use the camera of my android phone as a webcam for my PC to make international video calls and share screens. I know that LAN is completely different from WAN but I'll connect the phone through wifi and address like this `http://172.32.15.110:8080`

Does transferring the video through the LAN affect the processing power of the router (the processor chip inside the router)? Is it possible to affect the internet speed because both the local video and the international video pass through the same ethernet cable that is connected to my PC?

I already face some small issues but I want to make sure that this method will not affect the quality of the calls more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does a camera transmitting video use bandwidth? Yes.

Will that bandwidth mean the router is doing work? Yes.

Will that affect the processing power of the router? No more than any other device browsing the Internet or streaming video. It's what the router was designed to do.

Will it affect your PC speed? Yes, but only as much as the camera bandwidth is set to and it also depends on your Internet speed.

If you have gigabit ethernet between your router and computer then the camera bandwidth (probably less than 5Mbps) will be far less than your ethernet cable speed at 1gbps (1000Mbps). It is unlikely you will notice any significant difference at all.

If you have a normal 100Mbps ethernet cable which has been standard for years then you'll only notice a difference if your Internet speed is 100Mbps or higher.

If your Internet is limited to, for example, 20Mbps then that combined with the android camera is still far below what the cable can manage. It will be fine.